# GmailApp limitations with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, quota

I have a script running in google sheets that collects data via a Google Form. On form Submit triggers the script to run and create a PDF file which is then sent out as an attachment to a list of emails on my team which is anywhere from 15-30 people. Several of these are sent out per day as progress reports so the whole team can see daily progress.

The script keeps eventually failing and giving an error saying Gmail service is invoked too many times.

I am using `GmailApp.sendEmail`.

I have looked extensively through the google documentation on limits and quotas, but I cannot seem to understand why it is invoked too many times. It's my understanding that I should be allotted 1500 recipients per day with my business GSuite account.

This account sends through SMTP and also sends an attachment with every email. The script runs several times per day.

Comment: Do you send 15 to 30 emails or just one with 15 to 30 recipients.

Comment: is your app verified?

Comment: The script sends one email with about 20 recipients. It sends around 5 of those at the end of the day based on form submissions.

Comment: What does it mean to have the app verified?

Comment: `Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several billing cycles if they have fewer users.` [source](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#note1). Could it be that your G Suite domain was recently created?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have had the domain for a few years now. I think that it has to do with either the fact that the email server is not through google, or that the email has an attachment and the quota may be different for emails sent with attachment.

Comment: The email quota is dropping throughout the day without the script running. I set up a spreadsheet to check the quota and it returned this below:                                         
117 2020-07-02T18:01:37Z
111 2020-07-02T18:05:10Z
111 2020-07-02T18:05:15Z
111 2020-07-02T18:05:25Z
111 2020-07-02T18:05:27Z
96 2020-07-02T18:29:00Z
96 2020-07-02T18:29:03Z
96 2020-07-02T18:29:07Z
96 2020-07-02T18:29:09Z
81 2020-07-02T18:29:58Z
81 2020-07-02T18:31:33Z
81 2020-07-02T18:31:36Z
81 2020-07-02T18:33:55Z
81 2020-07-02T18:34:34Z
66 2020-07-02T18:41:56Z

Comment: Could you please provide the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: email.
    at GeneratePdf(Code:71:10)

Comment: I made a spreadsheet tool to test and list the Email quota remaining. Periodically I check the quote and it is dropping 15 every 20 minutes or so through the day. When my script runs, it drops the remaining by the appropriate amount but I can't explain the draining by 15 at a time.